# How to link to specific section in an external Doxygen html file?

Tags: hyperlink, documentation, doxygen

Let's say I have a section in a *doxygen* page `page_Examples` called `section_Example`. Is it possible to link directly to that section?

Linking to the page is done with `\link page_Examples Examples \endlink`, but I would like to go directly to the section! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
\ref section_Example Link Title
```

to create the link you're looking for. See the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref) for more information.